# How to use bottomNavigationBar in a separate file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code that is working properly:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screen_curiosities.dart';
import 'screen_movies.dart';
import 'screen_releases.dart';

import '../utils/side_menu.dart';
import '../utils/bottom_menu.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  List screens = [
    ScreenMovies(),
    ScreenReleases(),
    ScreenCuriosities()
  ];

  void onClicked(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Movies'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: screens.elementAt(selectedIndex),
      ),
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items:[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Movies',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
            label: 'Releases',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
            label: 'Curiosities',
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: onClicked,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red[800],
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Now I am trying to separate the Widget **BottomNavigationBar** to another file and call him on the property "bottomNavigationBar" from Scaffold. It would be like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu()
```

I did it with the Widget **Drawer** and it worked, but when I tried the same thing with bottomNavigationBar it wasn't successful.

When I try to use the variable **selectedIndex** in the new Widget it is always undefined.

I tried many things, but I couldn't solve this. Is there any way to use the Widget bottomNavigationBar in a separated file?

**EDIT**

Below, follow the 2 files that I need to make this link from the menu to the page in order to make them work together:

file home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screen_curiosities.dart';
import 'screen_movies.dart';
import 'screen_releases.dart';

import '../utils/side_menu.dart';
import '../utils/bottom_menu.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  List screens = [
    ScreenMovies(),
    ScreenReleases(),
    ScreenCuriosities()
  ];

  void onClicked(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Movies'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: screens.elementAt(selectedIndex),
      ),
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu() // Using the Widget here
  }

}
```

file bottom_menu.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items:[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Movies',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
          label: 'Releases',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
          label: 'Curiosities',
        )
      ],
      currentIndex: selectedIndex, // the variable is undefined
      onTap: onClicked, // the function is undefined
      selectedItemColor: Colors.red[800],
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: rickimaru, do you mean these two files? or the whole project?

Comment: The 2 files only. Just the minimal reproducible  code is enough.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question

Comment: @rickimaru, I editted the question.

Comment: Take note that a variable or a function from a different class can't be accessed directly. `selectedIndex` and `onClicked` is from `_HomeState`. Just a simple value and function reference passing to `BottomMenu` can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I did this here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy paste run two full code below 
You can pass `selectedIndex` and `onClicked` to `BottomMenu` 
code snippet

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu(
          selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
          onClicked: onClicked,
        ));
        
...     
class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final selectedIndex;
  ValueChanged<int> onClicked;
  BottomMenu({this.selectedIndex, this.onClicked});
```

working demo

[image]

full code `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'bottom.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  List screens = [ScreenMovies(), ScreenReleases(), ScreenCuriosities()];

  void onClicked(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Movies'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: screens.elementAt(selectedIndex),
        ),
        //drawer: SideMenu(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu(
          selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
          onClicked: onClicked,
        ));
  }
}

class ScreenMovies extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ScreenMovies"),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenReleases extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ScreenReleases"),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenCuriosities extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ScreenCuriosities"),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

full code `bottom.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final selectedIndex;
  ValueChanged<int> onClicked;
  BottomMenu({this.selectedIndex, this.onClicked});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Movies',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
          label: 'Releases',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
          label: 'Curiosities',
        )
      ],
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      onTap: onClicked,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.red[800],
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi chunhunghan, can you explain me this line? 

BottomMenu({this.selectedIndex, this.onClicked});

Comment: it's constructor of BottomMenu, it means receive two parameter selectedIndex and onClicked.

Comment: Ah ok, because I usually do the constructor of another way, passing parameters inside the parentheses and setting the values of propreties inside the keys sign. So thank you bro, it helped me ;)